# For two consecutive options, `getopts` taking the second option as the argument of first

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a code:

```
    while getopts ab:cde:f opt
    do
        case ${opt} in
            b|e)
                [[ ${OPTARG} = -* ]]   && usage "Invalid parameter \"${OPTARG}\" provided for agurment \"-        ${opt}!\""
                [[ ${#OPTARG} -eq 0 ]] && usage "Argument \"-${opt}\" requires a parameter!${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        esac

        case $opt in
            a) minusa=$opt;;
            b) minusb=$opt
            file_b=$OPTARG;;
            c) minusc=$opt;;
            d) minusd=$opt;;
            e) minuse=$opt
            file_e=$OPTARG;;
            f) minusf=$opt;;
            /?) echo Unrecognized parameter
             exit 1;;
        esac

    done
    echo  "minusa:$minusa","minusb:$minusb","file_b:$file_b","minusc:$minusc","minusd:$minusd","minuse:$minuse","file_e:$file_e","minusf:$minusf"
```

Simple code, just to understand the behavior of `getopts` command. When I run the script like:

```
    ./eg2 -b -f
    ./eg2: line 7: usage: command not found
    minusa:,minusb:b,file_b:-f,minusc:,minusd:,minuse:,file_e:,minusf:
```

It is taking the argument for option `-b` as `-f`. Whereas I want to print:

```
     [[ ${OPTARG} = -* ]]   && usage "Invalid parameter \"${OPTARG}\" provided for agurment \"-${opt}!\""
```

Where exactly in the code I'm going wrong? Also for the options `-b` and `-e` if there is no arguments , I want to print:

```
    [[ ${#OPTARG} -eq 0 ]] && usage "Argument \"-${opt}\" requires a parameter!${OPTARG}"
```

Kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

You've put a ":" after the "b" in `getopts` line.  That tells it to expect an argument afterwards.  If you don't want the next argument to be treated like an argument to `-b`, remove that ":".

Comment: You got my query wrong. I understand the way getopts is functioning, but in my code I want to put a condition that if someone puts `-b` option and without it's argument gives the next option, I want to print error message by putting this condition:
`[[ ${OPTARG} = -* ]]   && usage "Invalid parameter \"${OPTARG}\" provided for agurment \"-${opt}!\""` instead of the next option considered as the argument automatically for the previous option

Answer (score 0):

`[[ "${OPTARG}" =~ "^-[a-z]" ]]   && echo "Invalid parameter \"${OPTARG}\" provided for agurment \"-${opt}!\""` solves the problem...thanks